# change the color of a char

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change the color of a char in a string using C#? 
for ex.     MIND, make D to be red and the rest remain black.

I'm using a WINFORMS and I try to display it in a textbox, I can Use richtextbox as well.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Console? Label? Textbox?

Comment: Strings does not have color. You must be displaying the string in a control or something? Which one?

Comment: The answer entirely depends on how you're planning to display the string. Is it being printed to the console, displayed in a WinForms or WPF control, or what? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: winform, and its a textbox, i can use richtextbox as well.

Comment: @user363295: you may edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a RichTextBox at least.

```
// Save selection
var oldStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
var oldLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

// Select the text to change
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength - 1, 1);
// Change color
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

// Restore selection
richTextBox1.Select(oldStart, oldLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not. Strings have no color. PRESENTATION of strings may have a color, but that is not something you determine in the string.

Comment: I'm using a WINFORMS and I try to display it in a textbox, I can Use richtextbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the RichTextBox control, check out the tutorial on Syntax Highlighting presented here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/duncanharris/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp112012005050840am/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp1.aspx